# Where is social interaction data in GA when using mobile iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-analytics

In my iOS app I am using the Google Analytics for Mobile SDK and based on this page in GA documentation on Social Interaction tracking (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/social) my app is reporting social postings to GA using code like this:

```
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createSocialWithNetwork:@"Twitter"                                                                    
       action:@"Tweet" 
       target:targetUrl] build]];
```

or

```
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createSocialWithNetwork:@"Facebook"                                                                 
       action:@"Post" 
       target:targetUrl] build]];
```

But, I can't find where in the Google Analytics web site that I can find this data. According to research, it is supposed to be under All Traffic -> Social -> Plugins, and, since I use GA also for a web site, I checked in the web site property and did find this, but it is not in my Mobile App's "property" in GA. Obviously there are differences between GA for web and for mobile/iOS.

Does anyone know where in GA I could find the evidence that these social postings are actually being recorded?

Comment: I also facing the same issue :(

Comment: @Jordan Were you ever able to find this data? I'm unable to find it as well.

Comment: No, I gave up and created custom events instead.